# Update values on Jsp page retrieving from XML , whenever any update in the file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xmlupdate

I am displaying values in JSP by fetching from XML. Now my requirement is to refresh just the values not the entire page whenever any change takes place in XML. any suggestion how to do it in jsp. Code i have used for displaying have updated here, please suggest code for integrating auto refresh

now I want to auto update value of tag1 asap it gets updated in detail.xml

code I have added in comment

Comment: <%DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 doc = db.parse("http://localhost:8989/project/detail.xml");  
NodeList n1= doc.getElementsByTagName("tag_1");%>


<%= n1.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %>

Comment: You're looking at doing AJAX, look into http://prototypejs.org/ or some such, but this isn't small.